# How to include '<' in a folder name

Tags: spring, amazon-s3

Now working on a project and using Spring. There is an option where we have to create a folder name. Client insist that the folder name should allow '<' and '>'. But when i tried to do it if an alphabet comes after the '<' character the it is not taking the name.

For example if I type in a name '

Comment: Good luck if you are using windows. ':', '<', and '>' are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

That is one crazy requirement that you let slip through. While some systems and platforms allows **some** special characters in file and folder names, it's nowhere near uniform. Generally, best practice is to always limit file and folder names to letters and numbers.

Amazon S3 has strict rules on naming, basically only letters and numbers (see [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) for more information).

It might be best to take this requirement back to your client and inform them that this simply isn't supported.